# Wavelet transform stability to deformations

Tags: reference-request, signal-analysis, wavelets

I've come across the following claim in a [paper](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Emallat/papiers/ScatCPAM.pdf) of Mallat:

"High frequency instabilities [of a signal representation] to deformations can be avoided by grouping frequencies into dyadic packets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, with a wavelet transform."

I know what the wavelet packet decomposition is and I know what stability to deformations is (in the case of $C^2$ diffeomorphisms), but I don't understand why the quoted statement is true.

Perhaps I missed the explanation in the paper, but could someone provide a reference, an explanation or both? I assume it has something to do with the fact that a wavelet is localized.

<sup>1</sup> Stéphane Mallat: *Group Invariant Scattering*,
Communications on Pure and Applied Mathematics, Vol. LXV, 1331–1398 (2012), [DOI: 10.1002/cpa.21413](https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.21413)

Comment: What paper is that? Knowing the paper probably makes answering easier.

Comment: I've added the link to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Stability along log-frequency is attained via the constant Q transform, and along time via temporal averaging; this is proven in [Theorem 2.12](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2286). Explained visually [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076), also see ["Properties summary"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78515/50076).